# D glGenVertexArrays without GLEW

Tags: opengl, d, glew

I want to fully use OpenGL 3.3 in my program, but `glGenVertexArrays` segfaults without some special initialization. I've looked at the GLEW source but couldn't find what is done for it to work.

I tried binding to GLEW, but OPTLINK either says the library is invalid (when compiled with VS2012) or the symbol is not found (`uint glewInit()` in a MinGW dll converted to lib with implib).

If there are only a few lines needed doing what GLEW does (I suppose I don't need 1000 lines of function getting) I would like to do that myself, when it's too much I would appreciate some help on building a lib that D actually accepts.

Comment: I don't know anything about D, but I was under the impression that D was able to link to C libraries (though compiling with VS might be a problem). If you want to learn how to [manually load OpenGL function pointers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions), you can, but it will be extremely tedious to do it by hand for the hundreds of OpenGL 3.3 functions. You could simply try a [different loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: I just need one thing, keeping glGenVertexArrays from segfaulting. DMD has a weird linker, not every library file is supported.

Comment: Then you need to keep `glBindVertexArrays` from segfaulting. Next, keep `glVertexAttribPointer` from segfaulting. I can continue on and name *every GL 1.2+ function* you might use, but I think you get my point. You need to load the functions you want to use. You can either do this yourself or get a library for it.

Comment: I see. I got it to link properly by building a dll with VS and then converting it with implib now, but it still segfaults. glewExperimental is set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good start : http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions

Follow the links to The OpenGL Registry : http://www.opengl.org/registry/

Here you can find useful header files for your platform. I would recommend using GLEW or similar libs though.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I got GLEW to link properly now, but it doesn't seem to update the function pointers provided by Derelict.. meh, lots of hacking ahead.

Comment: Have you tried setting OpenGL version before calling glewInit? (GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR using glfwOpenWindowHint(..)) Also try with glewExperimental = GL_TRUE

Comment: I'm using Derelict 3 which supports OGL up to 4.1, but your hint did it. I just had to call DerelictGL.reload().